# How to remove covering lines?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, line

I have a shapefile where there are polygons perfectly fitting, I created  contour lines from all of the polygons so I have a shape containing only the lines. My problem is as the polygons were fitting, most of the lines cover each other. I cannot merge them because I need to keep the attributes of the lines.

What is the best way to get rid of the unnecessary second lines? ArcGIS or QGIS usage is preferred.

Comment: How did you create the lines? if the polygons are perfectly fitting a tool like Polygon to Line http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003t000000 will not create duplicate lines, then follow with Polygon Neighbors http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000045000000 to access the polygon information on BOTH sides of the line.

Comment: As Michael says, if you convert polygons to lines some part of that process either has to discard attributes from the polygons (you say you need to keep attributes) or create duplicate lines for each polygon sharing that edge (in which case they aren't unnecessary). It's unclear from you question exactly what you are trying to do and how you want to handle this attribute issue - please edit to describe in more detail what you have and what your end goal is. There are tools to delete duplicate lines, combine attributes of two identical geometries, or create single lines in the first place.